# Proper way to validate a table with Boolean methods and properties

Tags: c#, boolean

```
public class TableProcessor : TableFormat, ITableProcessor
{
    public List<Parts> PartsList { get; set; }
    public List<Parts2> Parts2List { get; set; }
    public List<Parts3> Parts3List { get; set; }
    public bool IsTableValid { get; set; }

    public TableProcessor(List<List<object>> Table) : base(Table)
    {
        PartsList = GetPartsList();
        Parts2List = GetParts2List();
        Parts3List = GetParts3List();
        IsTableValid = IsTableValid();
    }

    private List<Parts> GetPartsList()
    
    private List<Parts2> GetParts2List()
    
    private List<Parts3> GetParts3List()
    
    public bool ListsCountSame()
    
    public bool ListsContainCertainObject()
    
    private bool IsTableValid()
    {
        bool ListsCountSame = ListsCountSame();
        bool listsContainCertainObject = ListsContainCertainObject();

        if(!ListsCountSame || !listsContainCertainObject)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        return true;
    }        
}
```

In this class I'm processing a parsed table and creating list of objects from the table. Once lists are created I need to check if the values in the original table were correct.
For that I use two boolean methods that later combine into the one and also create a property to execute the check in constructor.

My concern is that the boolean property is there just to execute the check and exit the program if something was wrong in the raw table. Nowhere else the boolen property is utilized later on and I feel like it is not a good practice to do it. Or is it ok? The problem here is that the checks have to be done once all lists are created, otherwise I'd include that in methods of other properties.

**UPDATE**:

I ended up changing all boolean methods to void and removed the bool property, since the purpose of these methods is to exit the program if incorrect data is provided outside

```
public TableProcessor(List<List<object>> Table) : base(Table)
    {
        PartsList = GetPartsList();
        Parts2List = GetParts2List();
        Parts3List = GetParts3List();
        TableValidation();
    }

    private List<Parts> GetPartsList()
    
    private List<Parts2> GetParts2List()
    
    private List<Parts3> GetParts3List()
    
    private void ListsCountCheck() //Environment.Exit(0) if check is failed
    
    private void ListsContainCertainObjectCheck()//Environment.Exit(0) if check is failed
    
    private void TableValidation()
    {
        ListsCountCheck()
        ListsContainCertainObjectCheck()
    }        
}
```

Comment: I would change the `IsTableValid()` method into something like `private void ValidateTable()` and the `IsTableValid` property into `public bool IsTableValid { get; private set; }`. This kind of question is opinion-based though. It might work on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but you'd have to post complete code.

Comment: Also, are you aware that the `IsTableValid()` method currently returns `true` even if only one of the two variables equals `true`?

Comment: Ah yes, public bools are private, I just tested the code in Main() and have not set it back to private, sorry. My main question was is that ok in general to use such construction with boolean property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your example correctly, `IsTableValid` can only ever be observed to be true, and then it does not provide any actual information and is useless.

An important point is what you communicate with the user of your class. A method or property named `IsTableValid` should return a boolean. A method that explicitly throws or exits should be clearly marked as such, i.e. `ValidateTableOrThrow`. A class should probably *not* exit when the constructor is run, because that would not be expected by the user. As a rule of thumb, methods should throw exceptions rather than calling Exit for invalid data, since that lets you provide a descriptive message and allow the user of the class to handle the error, or allow the exception to propagate to crash the application.

Comment: Thank you! Sure, detailed information is passed to the user (this is not an exception, but just incorrect data provided outside that prevents correct execution of further logic, e.g. a negative number instead of positive), I just skipped all unnecessary code, as my question was more like "is it bad practice to include (to perform a check) in the constructor a property and a method that won't be used later on"

Comment: @HumbleNewbie "incorrect data provided outside that prevents correct execution of further logic" - This sounds like a perfect case for an `ArgumentException`. An `Environment.Exit(0)` is *much* harder to debug and understand than an exception with a suitable message. So it should be reserved for cases where there is no other option. A programmer mistake should typically be handled by casting an exception, since that makes it so much easier to find and correct the mistake.